# sudo - howto confirm execution but not requesting password

Tags: sudo

I am searching for a way to configure `sudo` to not ask for a password (e.G. adding the `NOPASSWD` to the `/etc/sudoers` configuration but echoing the command to be executed for confirmation by asking something

*Shall command `cat /etc/passwd` be executed? (y/N)*

Comment: Who does this command get echoed to? Who is to approve it? How does this link to sudo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the below function may be able to solve your prompt problem:

```bsh
sudo () {
    local command=$@
    read -rp "Shall command $command be executed? (y/N): "
    local YORN_RESP="$(grep -i "[YN]" <<<"${REPLY:0:1}" || echo 'N')"
    if [[ "$YORN_RESP" == [Yy] ]]; then
        command sudo "$@"
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```

As long as this function is loaded it will take precedence over the `sudo` command, however it will not prevent people from executing `/bin/sudo` directly.

For the no password sudo it sounds like you have already found the solution but you need to uncomment the following line in your `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: I don't think you want `$@` there in the `read`.

Comment: Have you tried actually running your code?

Comment: Try `sudo cat /etc/passwd`...

Comment: Ah yea it doesn't work with white space. Thanks

Comment: Updated, I think that fixes the issue.

Comment: You should use `command sudo` instead of `/bin/sudo`, since `sudo` may not always be located in `/bin`. And you can remove a bunch of `local` declarations if you run it in a subshell (`sudo () ( ... )` instead of `sudo () { ... }`).

Comment: Also, drop `RESP` and use the default `REPLY` variable that `read` puts its data into.

Comment: From a UI perspective, I’d expect to be able to hit Enter at that prompt and have it assume Y; you seem to be requiring an entry. I’d suggest accepting an empty result as Y or lowercasing the Y in the prompt.

Comment: Updated.  I've made it default to `N` as that seems to be what OP wants, but I have also changed the wording to indicate that.